# restrict access to data loaded from WCF service based on user

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

I am looking for the best solution to the following scenario. So far I haven't been able to find a solution.

I have an ASP.net application that provides managers of different departs the ability to log in and display different data based on their department. A manager might also have rights to view other departments or to view all departments. What departments they can and can't view is stored in a database table. At the time of coding the departments and how many exist is unknown as departments can be added and removed by the Administrator.

The data for the ASP.net application is accessed through a WCF database service. Which includes contracts like, GetSales(), GetDepartments, GetSale(int ID) etc.

So what would be the best way to allow a manager to use GetSales() or similar contract, but filter the results so that the user only gets Sale pertaining to those departments that he has rights to?

I am using a custom role and membership provider, so have considered using this as an option to send the users login name to the WCF service and then having the database filter the results based n table joins.However, I am sure there is a better option for doing this.

Any advise is appreciated.